# Should I retain html markup when performing language translation (ie via MS translate API)?

Tags: translation, bing-api, language-translation

Is there any advantage in passing html fragments to the translation API as opposed to only plain text. For example, translating the following

```
Please click <a href='#'>here</a> to continue
```

returns a valid, translated html fragment - but what happens under the hood? Is the returned translation equivalent to the translation of three sentence fragments

`Please click` > `here` > `to continue`

Or the single sentence

`Please click here to continue`

Why do I ask?
I have one or two html fragments that are larger than the permitted size and I need to chunk them up in some-way. Using the htmlagilitypack I could just replace the html document text nodes with the translated equivalent values but do i lose anything by doing this? Will the quality of the translation improve if I translate whole sentences (ie `<H1>`, `<H2>`, `<p>` tags)

Many thanks in advance

Duncan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07021227-7cc7-497e-9686-431679a70227/parsing-html-fragments) I got the following reply:

> In the translation it matters where the sentence boundary lies. HTML
>   markup has sentence-internal elements, like `<em>` or `<a>`, and sentence
>   breaking elements, like `<p>`. HTML mode will process the elements
>   according to their behavior in HTML document rendering.

So there it is!